# "SyntaxError: Unexpected token )" in javascript call when eval(value) is null?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a javascript call in `OnClientClick` that looks like the following:

```
OnClientClick='<%# "return DisplayAlert(" + Eval("BedNum") + "," + Eval("ClientId") + ");" %>'
```

And this is my javascript function:

```
    function DisplayAlert(bed, clientid) {
        if (clientid == null) {
            alert('value is null 1st if');
        }
        if (clientid === null) {
            alert('value is null 4th If');
        }
        if (clientid !== null) {
            alert(clientid);
        }

        return false;
    }
```

`ClientId` is always either *null* or has a valid value. When `ClientId` has a valid value, the `alert` is displayed. So that's fine.

But when `ClientId` is *null*, the `alert` is not displayed and the console shows `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )`.

I'm thinking that the javascript function call is not well-formed when `clientid` is null, and that's why I'm getting this error. But I have no idea how to fix it. I can always replace the *null* with a more manageable value, but I'll do that if there's no other choice.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Change to `<%# "return DisplayAlert('" + Eval("BedNum") + "','" + Eval("ClientId") + "');" %>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I just need to know if clientid is null, I ended up checking the length of clientid, instead of the actual value. And in the javascript function I check if it's 0:

```
OnClientClick='<%# "return ShowRoom(" + Eval("BedNum") + "," + Eval("ClientId").ToString().Length + ");" %>'
```

and the javascript function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowRoom(bed, clientid) {
        if (clientid == 0) {
            //clientid is null. Do something.
        } else if (clientid > 0)
        {
            //clientid is not null. Do something else.                
        }
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem comes from the construction of your function *call*.
When ClientId is null...

this: `<%# "return DisplayAlert(" + Eval("BedNum") + "," + Eval("ClientId") + ");" %>`
produces this: `return DisplayAlert(value, );`  *Notice the blank space*

try your function directly in JS "DisplayAlert(value, null);" and your first 2 alerts will show

That said, it's best if you change null to a more manageable value **before** your function call is created.

Comment: Thanks for your post. But there has to be a way to change this without changing the results of the dataset.

Comment: I didn't mean to change the value from the source, but rather in the construction of your call. For example, create a method in you code-behind that checks "CliendId" for null, if it is, change it to zero, like this: ..."," + CheckforNull(Eval("CliendId")) + ");".... then it will result in "return DisplayAlert(value, 0);"